# Bluetooth headphones not shown as output device (fresh 22.10)

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I just did a fresh install of 22.10. My Sony bluetooth headphones are connecting but not showing in the output devices.

Seems to be a few posts on this for upgrades but this is a clean install (so using Pipewire).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue and I have to disable and re-enable the connection through Bluetooth settings to get my headphones to work.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1288696)